# force subprocss to return a value before importing a module

Tags: python, unit-testing

Objective : To Create UnitTestCases for main.py
How can we run subprocess.run as unittest case

File : main.py

```
import os
_ENV = os.environ['server']

BASE_PATH = '/home/test'
SERVER_URL = {
    'DEV':{'ENV_URL':'https://dev.net'},
    'UAT':{'ENV_URL':'https://uat.net'},
    'PROD':{'ENV_URL':'https://prod.net'}
}[_ENV]

if _CYBERARK=='DYNAMIC' and _ENV.upper() in ('DEV','UAT','PROD') :
      TOKEN = json.load(open(BASE_PATH + "secrets/cyberark_env.json"))
      APPID = CONFIGURE_TOKEN.get('desc').get('appID')            

      ## --> error on this because its running .sh files
      VALUE=subprocess.run(["sh",BASE_PATH + "bin/cyberark.sh",APPID],capture_output=True,text=True).stdout.strip()
```

In my test_main.py
I am trying to import main.py to my test.py without any issues, but i find it challenging on how we to manually make VALUE variable return as 'ABCD'
Similar to below scripts

Testing : test_main.py

```
import unittest, sys
from unittest import mock

os.environ['server']='DEV'

# Similar to os.environ , i want to create temporarily VALUE before import main is called.
sys.path.insert(1, 'C:/home/src')
import main.py as conf


class test_tbrp_case(unittest.TestCase):
    def  test_port(self):
        #function yet to be created
        pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Is this achieveable or i need to relogic my whole function

Comment: _make VALUE variable return as 'ABCD'_, what do you mean specifically ?

Comment: For a unit test you should not depend on a bash script (have a test for the bash script, but don't test your bash script through the python call. That would be an integration or system test. It is possible to 'bypass' the subprocess.run call and check only if it was called with the right parameters (see [pytest-mock](https://pytest-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but to make this fully testable you'd need to restructure your code (e.g. put some code in a method).